# How can I set a specfic Wordpress page as landing page (but it should keep the permalink)?

Tags: wordpress, url, permalinks

I'd like to set the Wordpress page https://hartmannventures.com/success-stories/ as landing page. It should keep the permalink as it is now (/success-stories). Furthermore, the "home" page https://hartmannventures.com/ should keep it's permalink like it is now (/). I tried to set it with the static page settings, but then the "Success Stories"-page turns into the home page (/).

Thanks for your help!

[General Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuVe0.png) (I'm afraid of changing something of that)

[Reading Settings (Static Page)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVK4Z.png) (That's what didn't work -> Changed it back to Home again)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a separate template page inside them for that page, with that you no need worry about anything and it will not affect on the home page.

Answer (score 1):

Template Format

```
<?php  /* Template Name: Template name*/ ?>
<?php get_header();?>

HTML

<?php get_footer();?>
```